# How to pass an element-value variable from Javascript html file to code.gs file in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have two dropdown lists, one is dependent on the other.
When the user selects an option from the first list, the second dropdown list populates its items options from google SpreadSheet array (based on filter and map properties).

The question is:
How can I pass the element value from an Html script file to google apps script **code.gs** file 
so I can filter the second dropdown list depending on the selection chosen by the user from the first list?

**ReceivePayment-js.html** file:

```
  <script>

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
   var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
   });

   document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",populateData);             
   document.getElementById("reference").addEventListener("onchange",dropDown);     


   //Trying to pass this directly below variable that contains the value of Reference dropdown-list 
   //(onchange event listener) to code.gs file inside doGet function 
   //where my lists coded to be created dynamically and evaluated.

   function dropDown(){
   var selectedRef =  document.getElementById("reference").value;
   }

</script>
```

**Code.gs** file:

```
function doGet(e){
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
       var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Account lists");

       var receivePaymentTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Consol");  
       receivePaymentTemp.title = "Receive Payment";  

       var bankAcountsList = ws.getRange(2,6,ws.getRange("F2").getDataRegion().getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
       var htmlBankAcountList = bankAcountsList.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
       receivePaymentTemp.bankAcountsList = htmlBankAcountList

       var receivePaymentRef = ws.getRange(2,8,ws.getRange("H2").getDataRegion().getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
       var htmlreceivePaymentRef = receivePaymentRef.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
       receivePaymentTemp.receivePaymentRef = htmlreceivePaymentRef



       var chartOfAccounts =  ws.getRange(2, 1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
//Here where I need to get the value of document.getElementById("reference").value from the other side
//(ReceivePayment-js.html) and put it inside referenceBox variable as I obviously didn't succeed 
           var referenceBox = ""
           var filteredReference = chartOfAccounts.filter(function(item){ return item[0] === referenceBox; });
           var htmlfilteredCustomer = filteredReference.map(function(acN){ return '<option>' + acN[1] + '</option>'; });
           receivePaymentTemp.chartOfAccounts = htmlfilteredCustomer

       return receivePaymentTemp.evaluate();         
       }
```

**Consol.html** file:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
      <select id="creditAccount">
      <option disabled selected>Customer</option>
      <?!= chartOfAccounts; ?> 
      </select>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>
```

I have tried so far to put

```
document.getElementById("reference").value;
```

inside Code.gs file but it returned an error.

**Since I am new to coding, I got lost and can't figure out how it should be done properly.
Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

This example does the same thing.  It has three dependant dropdowns.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('res') ?>
    <?!= include('css') ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Select State, County and City</h1> 
    <br /><select id="selst" class="control" onChange="selectState();"> 
      <option value="" selected></option>
    </select>State
    <br /><select id="selco" class="control" onChange="selectCounty();"> 
      <option value="" selected></option>
    </select>County
    <br /><select id="selci" class="control" onChange="selectCity();"> 
      <option value="" selected></option>
    </select>City
    <div id="msg"><h2>Data Available from:</h2><p><a href="https://github.com/grammakov/USA-cities-and-states" target="_blank">https://github.com/grammakov/USA-cities-and-states</a></p></div> 
    <input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />
   <?!= include('script') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#selst').css('background-color','#ffff00');
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(sObj){
      console.log(sObj.vA);
      updateSelectList(sObj);
    })
    .getStates();
  });

  function updateSelectList(sObj){
    var select = document.getElementById(sObj.id);
    select.options.length=1; 
    if(sObj.vA){
      for(var i=0;i<sObj.vA.length;i++)
      {
        select.options[i + 1] = new Option(sObj.vA[i],sObj.vA[i]);
      }
    }
    $('#' + sObj.id).css('background-color','#ffffff');
  }

  function selectState() {
    $('#selco').css('background-color','#ffff00');
    var state=$('#selst').val();
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(sObj){
      updateSelectList(sObj);
    })
    .getCounties(state);
  }

  function selectCounty() {
    $('#selci').css('background-color','#ffff00');
    var county=$('#selco').val();
    var state=$('#selst').val();
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(sObj) {
      updateSelectList(sObj);
    })
    .getCities(state,county);   
  }

  function selectCity() {
    //do nothing for now
  }
  console.log('My Code');
</script>
```

code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  menu();
}

function menu() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
  .addItem('Show Districts Dialog','showDistrictsDialog' )
  .addItem('Create Named Rage', 'jjeSUS1.createNamedRange')
  .addItem('Select Columns Skip Header', 'jjeSUS1.selectColumnsSkipHeader')
  .addItem('Update States Global', 'updateStatesGlobal')
  .addItem('Create States Sheets', 'createStateSheets')
  .addItem('Delete States Sheets', 'deleteStateSheets')
  .addItem('Make State Sheet County Column Headers', 'makeStateSheetCountyColumnHeaders')
  .addItem('Clean Globals', 'cleanGlobals')
  .addToUi();
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('districts').evaluate();
}

function getStates() {
  var states=String(getGlobal('States')).split('~~~');
  var sObj={vA:states,id:'selst'};
  return sObj;
}

function getCounties(state) {
  var state=state || 'Colorado';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(getGlobal('DataSSID'));
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('USCities');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var counties=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][2]==state && counties.indexOf(vA[i][3])==-1) {
      counties.push(vA[i][3]);
    }
  }
  var sObj={vA:counties.sort(),id:'selco'};
  return sObj;
}

function getCities(state,county) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(getGlobal('DataSSID'));
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('USCities');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var cities=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][2]==state && vA[i][3]==county && cities.indexOf(vA[i][4])==-1) {
      cities.push(vA[i][4]);
    }
  }
  var sObj={vA:cities.sort(),id:'selci'};
  return sObj;
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function showDistrictsDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('districts').evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface,'US Cities, Counties and States')
}
```